# Google Analytics campaign tracking on Single Page Website

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

we've made a Single Page Website which identifies the page to be loaded by using a #!. Now whenever we load a page we manually track a pageView on Google Analytics but this pageview tracking doesn't recognize our campaign tracking query parameters .. they are send in the utmp attribute but Google doesn't do anything with the info. I think Google does something else for campaign tracking. Any idea how to fix this? Our url's are like this:

```
http://vlaamseopera.be/nl/#!/producties/la-forza-del-destino?utm_source=newsletter-feb12&utm_medium=email&utm_content=link-txt&utm_campaign=newsletter
```

so the page is loaded and then a request is made to load this page:

```
/producties/la-forza-del-destino?utm_source=newsletter-feb12&utm_medium=email&utm_content=link-txt&utm_campaign=newsletter
```

then a pageview is tracked for:

```
/producties/la-forza-del-destino?utm_source=newsletter-feb12&utm_medium=email&utm_content=link-txt&utm_campaign=newsletter
```

but google doesn't do anything with the campaign info. Any ideas?

btw, i know you can use setAllowAnchor .. but i have more information then just the campaign info after the hash.

kind regards,

Daan

Answer (score 1):

Maybe load

```
/producties/la-forza-del-destino?utm_source=newsletter-feb12&utm_medium=email&utm_content=link-txt&utm_campaign=newsletter
```

first, record GA data, and then redirect it to the single-page app?

Comment: I already do a redirect from /producties/la-forza-del-destino to the one with the hash ... this is for no javascript enabled browsers. But maybe i indeed can change this ... one problem is that it will track two pageviews then one on the /producties/la-forza-del-destino and one on the ajax page.

Comment: A not so clean solution would be to conditionally record the campaign depending on whether user came from the static page or came directly to dynamic page, by attaching a marker at the end of the URL during the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to workaround i can do is using this URL: http://vlaamseopera.be/nl/?utm_source=newsletter-feb12&utm_medium=email&utm_content=link-txt&utm_campaign=newsletter#!/producties/la-forza-del-destino

Now when the homepage is loaded the utm parameters are available, and the cookie is created.